# How to render without evaluating keyframes?

Tags: rendering, workflow

I've got some keyframes set up and don't quite like the way things look. I'm playing with some values to see if I can't make it look nicer.

When I render to see the affect of my changes, everything pops back to the keyframed (or interpolated) values. Is there a way to render *the current state of the scene*, regardless of any keyframes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to *mute* all channel in current object's animation data. Muting Actions and NLA strips can be done by pressing <kbd>LMB</kbd> on speaker button at each action channels or NLA track.

A faster way if involving lots of channels/tracks is to press <kbd>A</kbd> with cursor placed atop channel list to select all channels (or select channels manually with <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>LMB</kbd>), then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>, and choose *Mute*:

[image: Muting several keyframes at once]